# Why is a comma used before a "y" in some cases?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

I was taught that a comma must be used this way.

One (of many other uses) is when you want to enumerate a list of items you have to use the comma and before the last element of the list the comma must not be used instead a "y/o" is used. Example:

> Al examen tengo que llevar lápiz, pluma y borrador.

Anyway, I've seen in books other uses of the comma where the comma is used just before the "y". So in which cases is allowed to use it that way?

Comment: In English, whether to use a comma before the conjuction in a list depends on stylistic standards. In most books, the comma will be included (`red, green, and blue`) , but in most newspapers and magazines where space is at a premium, it's omitted (`red, green and blue`). I wouldn't be surprised if it's the same in Spanish, but I don't know.

Comment: In English that's called the [Oxford comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).

Comment: In English it's also called the *Harvard comma*, and apparently *serial comma*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En efecto, no se debe hacer uso de la coma para separar elementos gramaticales cuando media alguna de las conjunciones *y*, *e*, *ni*, *o*, *u*, salvo en los siguientes casos (el siguiente texto es tomado de la *Ortografía de la Lengua Española*):

Se coloca una coma delante de la conjunción cuando la secuencia que encabeza expresa un contenido (consecutivo, de tiempo, etc.) distinto al elemento o elementos anteriores. Por ejemplo:

> Pintaron las paredes de la habitación, cambiaron la disposición de los
>   muebles, y quedaron encantados.

También cuando esa conjunción está destinada a enlazar con toda la proposición anterior, y no con el último de sus miembros. Por ejemplo:

> Pagó el traje, el boloso y los zapatos, y salió de la tienda.

Siempre será recomendable su empleo, por último, cuando el período sea especialmente largo. Por ejemplo:

> Los instrumentos de precisión comenzaron a perder su exactitud a causa de la tormenta, y resultaron inútiles al poco tiempo.

En una relación cuyos elementos están separados por punto y coma, el último elemento, ante el que aparece la conjunción copulativa, va precedido de coma o punto y coma. Ejemplos:

> En el armario colocó la vajilla; en el cajón, los cubiertos; en los estantes, los vasos, y los alimentos, en la despensa.

Answer (score 4):

There are certain rules as the usage of the comma. All is mentioned in the [RAE.](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=coma2)

Now the relevant rules that are mentioned in the rae are the following. You use the comma after a ***y, e, ni, o, u,*** this is used with copulative and disyuntive conjunctions:

1. A comma must be written before the conjunction when the sequence links the previous predicate. And not with the last of its coordinated members.

> Pagó el traje, el bolso y los zapatos, y salió de la tienda.
>
> No sé si ir de vacaciones a Francia o Italia, o quedarme en casa.

1. When two grammatically equivalent elements are linked inside the same statement if the last one of them is semantically heterogeneous in respect of the previous ones. (i.e. It doesn't introduce a element belonging to the same series or enumeration) To indicare normally a conclusion or a consecuence, it is written after the conjunction:

> Pintaron las paredes de la habitación, cambiaron la disposición de los muebles, pusieron alfombras nuevas, y quedaron encantados con el resultado.

1. When the conjunction has an adversative value (equivalent to **pero**) can go preceded by a comma:

> Le aconsejé que no comprara esa casa, y no hizo caso.

1. A comma has to be written before or after any of these conjunctions if immediatly before or after there is an interjection or any other element that has to be isolated by commas from the rest of the statement.

> Mi abuelo, que era un gran aficionado a la poesía, y el maestro del pueblo fundaron una revista literaria; Puedes venir con nosotros o, por el contrario, quedarte en casa todo el día.

Now it is very important to follow these rules because it can change the meaning of the phrase radically. For example:

> Me he vestido, como me indicaron.

(Me indicaron que me vistiera)

> Me he vestido como me indicaron.

(Me indicaron cómo debía vestirme)

> Mientras hizo lo que debía y todo salió bien, no hubo problemas;
>
> Mientras, hizo lo que debía y todo salió bien.

Source: RAE.